# Передача map через Bundle даёт Null

Tags: android, android-fragment, null, android-bundle

В главном фрагменте `"HomeFragment"` создаются 2 других под табы, один из которых называется `"HomeNewsFragment"`. Необходимо передать из главного в дочерний фрагмент `map`. Передать пробую через `Bundle`. В `"HomeFragment"`:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable("HashMap", map);
Intent intent = new Intent(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(), HomeNewsFragment.class);
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

`extras`, судя по логам, содержит нужную мне `map`. Далее в "HomeNewsFragment" принимаю:

```
 LinkedHashMap mapS = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
 Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

 if(bundle != null) {
    mapS = (LinkedHashMap) bundle.getSerializable("HashMap");
 }
```

В итоге `mapS` получается пустой, ибо `bundle = null`.
Не могу понять, где теряется `bundle`, почему он `null` ?

Создание фрагментов:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Events"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Photo"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
}
```

И собственно класс адаптера:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                HomeNewsFragment fragment1 = new HomeNewsFragment();
                return fragment1;
            case 1:
                HomeGalleryFragment fragment2 = new HomeGalleryFragment();
                return fragment2;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Так конечно нельзя передавать, этот интент никак не уйдет в вызов другого фрагмента

Comment: @ pavlofff , а как можно?

Comment: Способ [взаимодействия через колбэк](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/) (реакция на событие в одном из фрагментов). При начальном вызове самое простое передавать значение через [инстанс фрагмента](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/7566397)

Comment: @ pavlofff , это придётся `map` дробить на `key` и `value` ,передать их,  а затем в дочернем фрагменте из них воссоздать `map`, я так понимаю?*

Comment: В инстансе фрагмента в Bundle можно поместить HashMap, как сериализируемый объект (вы это делали в вопросе), тут такой же Bundle. Через колбэк можно передать вообще все что угодно, любой объект, достаточно объявить интерфейс с этим объектом (объектами)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фрагмент, который должен получить значение:

```
public class GetValueFragment extends Fragment {
    HashMap mapInFrag;

    public static GetValueFragment newInstance(HashMap map) {

       GetValueFragment frag = new GetValueFragment();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putSerializable("HashMap", map);
       frag.setArguments(args);
       return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {

         if(bundle != null) {
             mapInFrag = (HashMap) bundle.getSerializable("HashMap");
        } 
}
```

Вызов такого фрагмента из любого места в коде и передача значения:

```
GetValueFragment frag = GetValeFragment.newInstance(mapToFrag);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.container, frag).commit();
```

В результате этих манипуляций мы получим объект фрагмента `GetValueFragment`,а в поле этого фрагмента `mapInFrag` значение поля `mapToFrag`

Применительно к фрагментам в адаптере. Значение можно передавать через конструктор адаптера:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    HashMap map;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, HashMap map ) {
        super(fm);
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                HomeNewsFragment fragment1 = HomeNewsFragment.newInstance(map);
                return fragment1;
        }
    }
}
```

создание такого адаптера:

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), map);
```

Comment: оно конечно всё хорошо, но фрагменты у меня уже созданы через адаптер. дополню вопрос кодом как именно.